# Calculating Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

How can I calculate the non-zero Clebsch-Gordan coefficient $$⟨j_1 +j_2, j_1 +j_2 -2|j_1, m_1; j_2, m_2 \rangle$$ for all possible values of $m_1$ and $m_2$?

I know I may have to use $ ⟨j_2 +j_1, j_1 +j_2 -1| j_1, j_1 -1; j_2,j_2\rangle = \sqrt\frac{j_1}{j_2 +j_1} $ aswell as $ ⟨j_2 +j_1, j_1 +j_2 -1| j_1, j_1; j_2,j_2 -1\rangle = \sqrt\frac{j_2}{j_2 +j_1} $